# How to escape _ wildcard within Google app script sql?

Tags: google-bigquery

The function to run a standard sql query within the app script throws up an error when `_`is used within the sql. It is used within the condition filter to look for all names with `_x_`. Backslashes break the app script when used.

Within Google Apps Script: `var sql1 = 'sql string';`

Within sql: `WHERE lower(name) like "%\_x_\%"`

Update: I managed to find a workaround using `REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(name), r"(_x_)"` but am still interested to know if it works with the regular `LIKE` clause.

Comment: Hey there, i'm using bigquery. The backslashes work in BQ but not when the query is copied into Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your case using a modified sample code from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery).

I queried against a sample dataset using `where like "%_"`. Then, I write the results in a Google spreadsheet.The table I am querying in BigQuery is:

```
Row id 
1   _id_1212
2   id1212
```

The code I am using is below:

```
/**
 * Runs a BigQuery query and logs the results in a spreadsheet.
 */
function runQuery() {
  // Replace this value with the project ID listed in the Google
  // Cloud Platform project.
  var projectId = 'project_id';


//modified query
  var request = {
    query: 'SELECT * from `project_id.dataset.table` where id LIKE "%_id_%";'//it will also work for where like "%\_id\_%",
//configuring the query to use StandardSQL
     useLegacySql: false
  };
  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;

  // Check on status of the Query Job.
  var sleepTimeMs = 500;
  while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    sleepTimeMs *= 2;
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
  }

  // Get all the rows of results.
  var rows = queryResults.rows;
  while (queryResults.pageToken) {
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
      pageToken: queryResults.pageToken
    });
    rows = rows.concat(queryResults.rows);
  }

  if (rows) {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('BiqQuery Results');
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

    // Append the headers.
    var headers = queryResults.schema.fields.map(function(field) {
      return field.name;
    });
    sheet.appendRow(headers);

    // Append the results.
    var data = new Array(rows.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var cols = rows[i].f;
      data[i] = new Array(cols.length);
      for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
        data[i][j] = cols[j].v;
      }
    }
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, headers.length).setValues(data);

    Logger.log('Results spreadsheet created: %s',
        spreadsheet.getUrl());
  } else {
    Logger.log('No rows returned.');
  }
}
```

The output,

```
id
_id_1212
```

Both `where id LIKE "%_id_%"` and `where id LIKE "%\_id\_%"` work when I set the query to use ***StandardSQL*** (`useLegacySql: false`).

In addition, the error ***GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: Syntax error: Illegal escape sequence: \_*** will be thrown when trying to escape the underscore using a double backslash such as `where id LIKE "%\\_id\\_%"`.